# What is Relative Error of equation $2.3(4.18-3.24)$

Tags: numerical-methods, rounding-error

I've trying to solve it and here's my procedure:

$e1\:=\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-1}\:=\:5\cdot 10^{-2}$

$e2\:=\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-2}\:=\:5\cdot 10^{-3}$

$e3\:=\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-2}\:=\:5\cdot 10^{-3}$

$Relative\:Error\:=\:\frac{e1}{2.3}\:+\:\frac{e2}{4.18}\:+\:\frac{e3}{3.24} = 0.024478512$

**But the solution on my book is:**

$Relative Error: 0.03238$

Where am I missing?

Comment: please give us more information: what book, what is equation 2.3(4.18-3.24),...

Comment: @HQuser Not clear at all. What a question??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The exercise is done in order you combine absolute errors and relative errors.

You are considering $$x=a\times(b-c)=a\times d$$

$$d=b-c=(4.18\pm 5\times 10^{-3})-(3.24\pm 5\times 10^{-3})=0.94\pm 2\times 5\times 10^{-3}=0.94\pm 10^{-2}$$ So, now $$\frac{\Delta x}x=\frac{5\times 10^{-2}}{2.3}+\frac{ 10^{-2}}{0.94}=0.03238$$

**Edit**

With regard to the problem you wrote in comments, now, considering $$y=\frac{b-c}a=\frac da$$ $$d=b-c=(1.3384\pm 5\times 10^{-5})-(2.038\pm 5\times 10^{-4})=-0.6996\pm 5.5\times 10^{-4}$$ Now, the same as before $$\frac{\Delta y}y=\frac{5\times 10^{-4}}{4.577}+\frac{5.5\times 10^{-4}}{0.6996}=0.0008954$$ (this is exactly your result); this makes which makes $$\Delta y=0.00013686$$ which is exactly your result.

Either the book answer is wrong or we are both wrong (and I do prefer the last hypothesis !). More than likely, there is a typo in the book answer (it should be $0.13\times 10^{-3}$ and not $0.23\times 10^{-3}$).

Good to see that you made it correctly !

Comment: You are very welcome ! Did you understanf now this problem of error propagation when you have sums, differences, products, ratios and so on ?

Comment: I did understand a bit, can you please provide me some links where I can further study on this topic, I can't seems to find it on google or perhaps I am searching wrong, Also can I calculate relative error using online calculator sites like symbolab? Thank!

Comment: Search for *propagation of errors* in Wikipedia. Don't use online tools ! Understand first, please. This is the real key. The fact that you get the right number is (to me) irrelevant except if you know why and howIf I can help you, just contact me. Cheers.

Comment: I tried to solve the question: $(1.3384-2.038)/4.577$ here's what i Did:
1) I find out the R.E and A.E of $(1.3384 - 2.038)$ and got result: $A.E. = 5.5E-4$ and $R.E = 7.8616E-4$ then I solved the quotient part, through by adding previous R.E. to the R.E. of quotient and got the result: $R.E.=8.9540E-4$ and then I find out A.E. by calculating $(1.3384-2.038)/4.577$ and multiplying it by R.E. of $8.9540E-4$ and got result: $1.3686E-4$ but on book the AE is: $0.23E-3$, is answer on book incorrect?

Comment: @HQuser. You are perfectly correct and I am happy you made it. I edited my answer for this second part. Go on ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-) just final question, if I am given values 1.00 + 223, how will i find errors of them? here's my approach: error for $1.00 = 1/2 * E-2$ and $223 = 1/2 * E-0$, is my approach correct?

Comment: @HQuser : It is fine $(1.00\pm 0.005)+(223\pm 0.5)=224\pm 0.505=224\pm 0.5$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47636/discussion-between-hquser-and-claude-leibovici).

Comment: Respected teacher, I have came across a question: 9.48 * 0.513 - 6.72. I wanted to know how to get the general value of it? like Z = 9.48 * (0.513 - 6.72) (this generates value of 58.8423) or like Z = (9.48 * 0.513) - 6.72 (this generates the value of 1.8567)?
in that case should I follow the BEDMAS rule or should I take right to left solving approach?

Comment: Compute first the relative error for $a=9.48\times 0.513$, then the corresponding absolute error and then the absolute error for $a-6.72$. Always the same story ! Cheers.

Comment: ah.. right, so in question like this: 0.25 * 2.84/0.64, I solve it like: $a = 0.25 * 2.84$ and then $a / 0.64$

Comment: for $x=\frac{a\times b}c$, use $\frac{\Delta x}x=\frac{\Delta a}a+\frac{\Delta b}b+\frac{\Delta c}c$. Do the same for $x=a\times b\times c$

Comment: ah.. right, basically I have to find both relative error and absolute error, finding relative error seems pretty easy now, but there's a slight confusion in absolute error, I can find absolute error like this: $A.E. = R.E. * Z$ where $Z = 0.25*2.84/0.64$, how to solve $Z$ part? like $Z = (0.25*2.84)/0.64$ or $Z = 0.25 * (2.84/0.64)$ in finding out $Z$, should I find according to right-to-left approach or by following BEDMAS rule?